# Neo4j count mismatch

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Neo4j version : 3.5.0

The counts are shown different by a good margin at a particular time.
How is that possible?
The label `count(*)` shows less number compared to `exists count(*)`

```
neo4j> MATCH (n:User) where exists(n.user_id) RETURN count(*);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 8340287  |
+----------+

1 row available after 1130 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
neo4j> MATCH (n:User) RETURN count(*);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 8322843  |
+----------+

1 row available after 5 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
```

Comment: Were any `User` nodes deleted between those 2 queries?

Comment: You may want to run a [consistency check](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/consistency-checker/) on your graph to see if there are any inconsistencies in the count store. Also, let us know what version of Neo4j you're using.

Comment: @cybersam no there was nothing deleted between these 2 queries

Comment: @InverseFalcon sure will run that.
neo4j version 3.5.0

Answer (score 1):

The version `3.5.0` has some bugs on the `count` feature (see the [changelog](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.5-changelog) )

I recommand you to upgrade ! The version 3.5.0 has many bugs, and the latest version is 3.5.11

To be sure that your issue comes from that, can you try to execute the sames queries with the prefix : `CYPHER runtime=slotted`

Example : `CYPHER runtime=slotted MATCH (n:User) RETURN count(*);`

If you have the same numbers as before, the bug comes from the version.

An other possibility is that the bug comes from the stats of the database.  To see if it's that can you run this query : `MATCH (n:User) WHERE id(n)>=0 RETURN count(*);`

Cheers

Comment: Tried `CYPHER runtime=slotted` for the above two queries and still the same numbers as before

Tried the other one as well and the counts still same as before

Comment: So as mentionned by @inverseFalcon, you should do a `consistency check` and also don't forget to do the upgrade.

Comment: The upgrade is important, we don't recommend using .0 releases in production, and try to stay current with upgrades when possible. We're at 3.5.11 right now, so you're nearly a year behind in patch releases and bug fixes.